# Указатели. Есть ли разница?

Tags: c, указатели

На сайтах и в книгах встречаются различные объявления и использование указателей:

```
char *p;
```

и

```
char* p;
```

Есть ли между ними разница? Когда какое написание используется?

Answer (score 4):

Абсолютно никакой, как и `char*p` или `char * p`. Компилятор просто игнорирует пробелы. Дело вкуса (или принятого в команде, где вы работаете, стиля программирования).

Но!

Запомните, что

```
char * p, i;
```

это объявление *указателя* `p` и переменной `i` типа `char` (`i` - **не** указатель!).